# Firebase Upload missing required dSYMs Not Working

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

Currently, I am facing issues to upload dSYMs through the new uploader script.

```
/path/to/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p <platform> /path/to/dSYMs
```

I am getting success response by uploading the dSYMs

[image]

But no change on firebase console.

[image]

I have already checked the following thread:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5327

Please let me know if anyone having a solution...

Comment: Please use [tag:google-fabric] tag, because [tag:fabric] is unrelated to your question, it is about python library. Take a look at the description of the tag

Comment: @Ashish kakkad  have u uploaded dsym through run script in build phases ? are u getting the crashes in firebase console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what is going on in the Firebase Crashlytics.

But after 1 Day/24 Hours the dSYMs processed and now they are showing (Optional) in the same build.

[image]

***Update***

I have again uploaded the dSYMs today, and it uploaded quickly. Maybe some issues are there with the Firebase Crashlytics upload process!

[image]

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/5228

Answer (score 1):

If this is a migrated app from Fabric, then you need to follow these directions,

"Important: If you're working with an app that you previously linked from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics, pass in your Fabric API Key to run the upload symbols script. That is, in the following options to run the script, use -a fabric-api-key instead of -gsp path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist."

If this is not a migrated app, and you're seeing that the correct missing UUID is being uploaded, but you're still getting the missing dSYM error, then you need to write into [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) so they can get your debug logs and check your session ID.

Comment: Thanks but, I already checked the documents for this... This is not the issue that I am talking :)

Comment: Your issue might be related to this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5327

Comment: I cannot find this message on Firebase documentation, Is still relevant?

Comment: @drasick https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios#the_run_and_upload-symbols_scripts_are_now_in_firebasecrashlytics

Comment: @OlegKodysh I cannot find this in the documentation
"Important: If you're working with an app that you previously linked from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics, pass in your Fabric API Key to run the upload symbols script. That is, in the following options to run the script, use -a fabric-api-key instead of -gsp path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist."
It actually said to move towards using FirebaseCrashlytics and do not mention if thee app is migrated or not.

Comment: @drasick that's the updated documentation. What I wrote above in my answer only applies if you migrated from Fabric, and linked your app into Firebase. This is no longer possible to do, so if you haven't already done it, then no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What I found:

1. You should double-check if you can find this specific DSYM in your XCode archive. For this, open XCode->Organizer->Show In Finder-> DSYMs in bundle: try to find specific DSYM by ID from the dSYMS error Firebase panel. If any you can find with the same ID, you have to upload manually.
2. On my practice, the delay is usually several mins, max 24 hours.
3. Sometimes, I couldn’t find the DSYM IDs listed on Firebase in XCode archive or from AppStore downloads. What I found, that Firebase catches all distributed versions of the app. That’s why you cannot find them on AppStore  if it is not on TestFlight yet. You probably can find them in your alpha archives.

However, this is my guessing.
I was wondering if anyone from Firebase guys can give more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

install crashlytics via POD 'Firebase/Crashlytics'.
download DSYMS from app store.
located here
--> myapps --> select your app --> testflight --> select latest build --> Build Metadata --> Download dSYM.

now run this script using Terminal directly

YOUR PROJECT POD FOLDER PATH /FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /YOUR PROJECT/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/username/Downloads/appDsyms

more in detail step.

Open terminal, drag and drop 3 files on terminal on this order:

A--> drag an drop: "upload-symbols" which can be found in /project/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols

B--> write " -gsp "

C--> drag an drop: "GoogleService-Info.plist" which can be found in /project/GoogleService-Info.plist

D--> write " -p ios "

E--> drag an drop: "appDsyms" folder (unarchived, zip file might not work!) which usually is in Download folder /Users/username/Downloads/appDsyms

F--> Press Enter

In terminal the complete command should include -gsp and -p ios, full command looks like this: A -gsp C -p ios E

/project/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /project/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/username/Downloads/appDsyms

it might take some time to reflact on google firebase 24 hours.

Comment: This issue is already fixed. Please check my answer. The issue was there at firebase...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is taking (around) 24 hr to process the dSYMs (specially, if dSYM size is large), but it should improve soon.

Most Impacted Developers:

- Fabric legacy only, not migrated customers - should no see impact
- Fabric legacy SDK, migrated to Firebase - impacted
- Fabric legacy SDK, onboarded via Firebase - impacted
- Firebase SDK (currently in beta) - no impact

It is suspected that the dsym downloaded from Apple has the incorrect bundle id. Apple is setting com.apple.xcode.dsym. (e.g. com.apple.xcode.dsym.Bingo Blast).

1- As a temporary workaround, if the developer after downloading the dsym from Apple, converted all occurrences of the incorrect bundle string with the correct bundle id (e.g. com.redhotlabs.bingo), this should allow the dsym to be ingested correctly.

See an example shell script that developers could use replacing the  and  with the appropriate values.

export BUNDLE_ID=''
export DSYM_PATH=''
sed -i '' -e "s/>com.apple.xcode.dsym.*\$BUNDLE_ID\

2- Try not test-crash the app or release a potentially crashy app to users for at least 10 minutes after upload-symbols has completed and the mapping file is uploaded.

3- I would recommend to upgrade to Firebase SDK (currently in beta) to avoid this issue all to gather.

Comment: I have downloaded dSYMs from Apple.

Comment: Do you have any open case/ticked AT Fabirc or Firebase Support ?

Comment: no... as I posted in answer it has taken almost one day to process...

Comment: Currently, it is taking (around) 24 hr to process the dSYMs (specially, if dSYM size is large), but it should improve soon.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you have any documentation for this time of 24 hours?